# How to do a hibernate session.close() after showing JSP to avoid lazy=false

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, session, struts2

The issue here is that I'm getting this exception:

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com..., no session or session was closed

I understand that this happens because I do a session.close() before I try to access certain information. I know as well that I can badly fix this by setting the lazy load lazy=false, but this loads every object of the set and the load of the JSP is then slow.

So the question here is how can I do a session.close() after the info is loaded on the JSP with lazy=true. It would be fine to know wether there is any other option to do this.

Below you have how I do the access to the database:

```
public Collection<Object> className(Object object){
    Session session = Conexion.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    ...
    Collection<Object> result = crit.list();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return result;
}
```

All the help you can give will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace? Also I don't understand is the question about managing Hibernate session or about exception. In order to give you a better advice sooner, post the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that all the information that is displayed in the JSP has been loaded. Setting lazy loading to false fixes that, but as you noticed, it then loads everything eagerly  and that can hurt performance.

So check your JSP, then make sure that collections and other lazily loaded things are in fact loaded at the time when the JSP is displayed (by modifying the fetch query, or explicitly fetching connected collections). This requires manual work from you, but then again, writing code is what you're being paid for.

Edit: Some examples how to do selective lazy loading.

Using HQL and fetch as described in [Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html):

```
"from Cat as cat left join fetch cat.kittens"
```

Even if Cat.kittens is normally a lazy collection, it would be eagerly fetched due to the explicit "fetch" statement.

Another way is to access the collection while the session is open, forcing the lazy fetching to happen:

```
Cat cat = ... // load Cat from database
int size = cat.kittens.size(); // Triggers a fetch for the collection
```

The first version is obviously cleaner.

Comment: I Kayaman, thanks a lot for your comment, I appreciate it. However, this does not really clarify me how can I do what you say (behavior and code wise) as for what you say, the only way I know I have to load the data to show in the JSP is to set lazy=false.

Comment: @Moises fetch them in the controller while the session is open.

Comment: This may sound really stupid… but I do I fetch it in the controller? I quite don't understand what the controller part is.

Comment: @Moises The code you posted is located in your controller. You should study up on hibernate a little bit, you can make an explicit fetch with HQL (so certain things aren't loaded lazily). Another way is to access the lazy-loaded collections in code during the data loading phase. I'll update the answer with some code examples.

Comment: @Kayaman now I understand what you guys mean... I thought the controller was what you said, but I got confused. This is my first web site with struts2 and hibernate. Be patient :)